# how can I do use Except() between two SelectListItem lists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I have two list of type `IEnumerable <SelectListItem>` I need to create a new `IEnumerable <SelectListItem>` with the elements of the first list that do not exist in the second list. how can i do this?

I tried to do it with a `Except()` but did not result...

Example code:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectListItemA = ....;
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectListItemB = ....;
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Except = SelectListItemA.Except(SelectListItemB);
```

Comment: I am not able to understand what you've written. Can you rephrase, please?

Comment: And perhaps add a code example so we can see what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
var items1 = new List<SelectListItem>();
var items2 = new List<SelectListItem>();
//[.. populate lists here ..]
var onlyInFirst = items1.RemoveAll(item1 => items2.Any(item2 => item1.Value == item2.Value));
```

`Except` requires that `Equals` and `GetHashCode` is implemented in the traversed class.

Comment: I've uploaded an example

Comment: +1 for mentioning that "Except requires that Equals and GetHashCode is implemented in the traversed class."