# I tried to do a "Except()" but it did not work

Tags: c#, except, selectlistitem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how can I do use Except() between two SelectListItem lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361554/how-can-i-do-use-except-between-two-selectlistitem-lists)

I have two list of type `IEnumerable <SelectListItem>` I need to create a new `IEnumerable <SelectListItem>` with the elements of the first list that do not exist in the second list.
how can i do this?

I tried to do it with a `Except()` but it did not work

Example code:

`IEnumerable<SelectListItem>  SelectListItemA = ....;`
`IEnumerable<SelectListItem>  SelectListItemB = ....;`
`IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Except = SelectListItemA.Except(SelectListItemB);`

Comment: What do you mean, "it didn't work"?

Comment: @L.B: He asked that question too :p

Comment: Really, don't ask the same question again, and certainly not half hour from the first time!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work, take alook at [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx):

```
            double[] numbers1 = { 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5 };
            double[] numbers2 = { 2.2 };

            IEnumerable<double> onlyInFirstSet = numbers1.Except(numbers2);

            foreach (double number in onlyInFirstSet)
                Console.WriteLine(number);

            /*
             This code produces the following output:

             2
             2.1
             2.3
             2.4
             2.5
            */
```

I guess the problem is that the Equality comparer in your case (for SelectedListItem) isnt defined, or better said things which look the same are not simply the same objects, in this case you will have to provide the [IEqualityComparer] to define which elements are actually equal[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx):

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Except<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> first,
    IEnumerable<TSource> second,
    IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer
)
```