# Remove one list from another mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have two lists of the same type and I am trying to subtract the information in one list from the other and then save the result into the model.

I have tried two ways of doing it and so far I can't get either to work:

These are the two lists:

```
List<ApplicationsDetailsModel> AppList = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<ApplicationsDetailsModel>("exec get_applications_r").ToList();
var AppExceptionList = new List<ApplicationsDetailsModel>();
foreach(var g in AnIrrelevantList)
        {
AppExceptionList.Add(new ApplicationsDetailsModel()
            {
                AppNum = g.AppNum,
                AppName = g.AppName
            });
}
```

So they now both have different data in the same format.

```
model.AppList = AppList.Except(AppExceptionList).ToList();
```

This doesn't bring up any errors but it also doesn't subtract the second list from the first.

```
var onlyInFirst = AppList.RemoveAll(a => AppExceptionList.Any(b => AppList == AppExceptionList));
```

I got this idea from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361554/how-can-i-do-use-except-between-two-selectlistitem-lists).

Anyone know where I am going wrong?

Comment: Are AppList and AppExceptionList of the same type? And do they contain different items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instances are not the same and are therefore not found to be equal by `Except` since it's checking for reference equal (which is obviously never going to be the case).  For your situation you need to write a custom equality comparer... I've taken a stab at it here...

```
public class ApplicationsDetailsModelEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<ApplicationsDetailsModel>
{
    public bool Equals(ApplicationsDetailsModel x, ApplicationsDetailsModel y)
    {
        return x.AppNum == y.AppNum && x.AppName == y.AppName;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ApplicationsDetailsModel obj)
    {
        int hashCode = (obj.AppName != null ? obj.AppName.GetHashCode() : 0);
        hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ obj.AppNum.GetHashCode();
        return hashCode;
    }
}
```

Usage...

```
model.AppList = AppList.Except(AppExceptionList, new ApplicationsDetailsModelEqualityComparer()).ToList();
```

Note that I'm assuming your AppNum and AppName together uniquely identify your objects in your list.

Comment: Thanks mate. That was actually simpler than I thought it would be hence me trying the LINQ first. Appreciate you taking the time to show me how it's done.

Answer (score 1):

The `Except` method doesn't know how to compare two objects of type `ApplicationsDetailsModel`. You need to tell him explicitly, using an `IEqualityComparer` :

```
public class ApplicationsDetailsModelComparer : IEqualityComparer<ApplicationsDetailsModel> {

    public bool Equals(ApplicationsDetailsModel first, ApplicationsDetailsModel second) {
        return first.AppNum == second.AppNum;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ApplicationsDetailsModel applicationsDetailsModel) {
        return applicationsDetailsModel.AppNum.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then, you use it like this :

```
model.AppList = AppList.Except(AppExceptionList, new ApplicationsDetailsModelComparer ()).ToList();
```

If `AppNum` isn't an unique value in your collection (like a primary key), feel free to adapt the comparer class to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

jgauffin's answer on the question that you linked to sums it up:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13361682/89092

Except requires that Equals and GetHashCode is implemented in the traversed class.
```

The problem is that the Except method does not now how to compare instances of ApplicationsDetailsModel

You should **implement GetHashCode in ApplicationsDetailsModel** to create a way to uniquely identify an instance

You should **implement Equals in ApplicationsDetailsModel** and use the result of GetHashCode to return whether or no the instances should be considered "Equal". It is probably best to do this by implementing the IEquatable interface: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx

**When you perform these steps, the Except method will work as expected**